# Receiving IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

When using the below code i receive this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25. Yet, I certainly declared the Player array. Any ideas why?

UPDATE:
Sorry it seems I never explained clearly:
There are 2 arrays present below, the Team[24] consists of 24 teams BUT, each team, has an entire Player[25] array as one of its attributes (with 25 players). The error, I am receiving, therefore, is not related to the Team[24] array but rather with the Player[25] array which does indeed have 25 elements.

```
private Team [] teamArr = new Team[24];
private int size = 0;

public TeamArr()
{
  String line, player, position, team;
  int ranking;
  double points;
  char group;
  Player [] playerArr = new Player[25];
  int sizeTeam = 0;

  try
  {
     Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("FIFA.txt"));
     while (inFile.hasNext())
     {
        line = inFile.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(line);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("#");
        ranking = sc.nextInt();
        team = sc.next();
        points = sc.nextDouble();
        group = sc.next().charAt(0);
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
           player = sc.next();
           position = sc.next();
           playerArr[sizeTeam] = new Player(player, position);
           sizeTeam++;
        }//while sc
        teamArr[size] = new Team(team, playerArr, sizeTeam, group, ranking,points);
        size++;
        sc.close();
     }//end while inFile
     inFile.close();
  }
  catch(IOException ex)
  {
     System.out.println("error in constructor " + ex);
  }

  }//end constructor
```

Comment: Your array has length 25 and has valid indices from 0...24. When you try to insert a Player at position 25 this is not a valid index and will result in IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Please look at the update, my apologies.

Comment: For every team you have to set the sizeTeam variable back to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `playerArr` array is limited to 25 Players. 
You have nested loops. The internal loop initializes the `playerArr`, each time assigning a `Player` to `playerArr[sizeTeam]`.

However, you initialize `sizeTeam` just once, before reading the first team :

`int sizeTeam = 0;`

Therefore, when you read the second team, `sizeTeam` is already `25`, which gives you the exception.

Fix :

```
  try
  {
     Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("FIFA.txt"));
     while (inFile.hasNext())
     {
        line = inFile.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(line);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("#");
        ranking = sc.nextInt();
        team = sc.next();
        points = sc.nextDouble();
        group = sc.next().charAt(0);
        sizeTeam = 0; // this is the only change needed
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
           player = sc.next();
           position = sc.next();
           playerArr[sizeTeam] = new Player(player, position);
           sizeTeam++;
        }//while sc
        teamArr[size] = new Team(team, playerArr, sizeTeam, group, ranking,points);
        size++;
        sc.close();
     }//end while inFile
     inFile.close();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the teams in the text file do not contain more than 25 players per team (each team is listed on an individual line and all the players, with their positions, are listed after that.)

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the input text file, please?